# Sharepoint 2010. Api. How to get field history?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I have SPListItem and some text field. I need in code get all versions of this field
EX:

1. version 1 "hello rorld"
2. version 2
       "hello world"
3. version 3 "new
       application"

Any examples how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (SPListItemVersion version in item.Versions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
        "{0}. version {0} \"{1}\"", 
        version.VersionId, version["this field"]));
}
```